# Notepad ++, how to delete duplicate lines, up to specific character and alphabetically order?

Tags: duplicates, notepad++

I am working with a dictionary file en_GB.dic.

Problem 1: There is a new updated en_GB.dic and when compared in Notepad++, i want to auto transfer missing words from new en_GB.dic to my current en_GB.dic. I do not want to transfer same words like abdominal/YS when i have abdominal/SY.

Problem 2: Assuming problem 1 can not be done and i have to copy and paste new en_GB.dic to my current en_GB.dic, there will be thousands of duplicate lines. Easy to remove the obvious duplicates. But i can't seem to remove duplicates like this below, as an example.

```
abdominal/SY

abdominal/YS
```

I want to check up to character / for duplicate and remove the abdominal/YS as /YS is not in alphabetical order and keep abdominal/SY. There are thousands of examples that need removing.

Thanks in advance for any replies and hopefully solutions.

Comment: What have you tried? and what didn't work?

Comment: This won't be possible in Notepad++ without a plugin.  There are several: https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=nppscripts https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/15297/scripts-creating-editing

Comment: I must be missing something, but why not simply replace en_GB.dic with the new version instead of manually looking for differences and copy them to the old file?

Comment: @Julio. I do a lot of modifying subtitles and new words are added to the dictionary thus i have words that's not in the "latest" downloaded version.

Comment: @user10246830 – why not to load you dictionary into a database and maintain and merge it with later dictionary versions there? Then, always only export the latest merged result as updated en_GB.dic. You know how much this is worth the effort.